# Upgrade Windows Store app which includes SQLite

Tags: sqlite, windows-store-apps

I have an app in the Windows Store which utilizes SQLite. I am releasing a minor release and am wondering how SQLite handles upgrades. Will I wipe out all my customers databases when they take the new release? Any thoughts on handling this issue in the release? (no change in my SQLite db structure)

Answer (score 2):

I am told that the data will remain intact if you make no changes to the schema of the db.

Here is the link from a Microsoft forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f4550181-468a-4902-9ee0-d8554a127f92/upgrade-windows-store-app-do-i-lose-sqlite-data